# Trying to append an html element using jquery on the fly using php based on button-click but nothing is showing

Tags: php, html, jquery

Trying to append an html element using jQuery on the fly using PHP based on button click but nothing is showing. Since it is created on the fly, I have kept the values of id and name properties of dynamic html elements with a counter variable so that later it can be differentiated from one another while saving to the database.

Following is the code

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php
          if (isset($_POST['checkexistingopp']))
        {
         $sql = "select l.id as LinkId, o.id, concat(o.Opponenttype,' - ', o.OpponentName , ' - رقم المرجعي - ',o.Refnumber,' ',o.OpponentCaser) as Opponent ,l.case_id,l.opponent_id  from wp_opponentcaselink l, wp_opponents o where  o.id=l.opponent_id and  l.case_id=".$_POST['case_id'];
     //echo $sql;
            if ($results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql))
      {
                $c=0;
                 $echomsg= "<script>
                    $(document).ready(function() { var str='';";
                foreach ($results as $result){
                    $linkid=$result->LinkId;
                    $RefNumber=$result->refnumber;
                    $case_id=$result->case_id;
                    $opponent_id=$result->opponent_id;
                    $opponent=$result->Opponent;
                    $c=$c+1;  //counter to differentiate names and ids of html elements
        
                    if (isset($opponent_id)) {
                    $echomsg.=" str=\"<br> <br><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"LinkId.$c.\" name=\"LinkId.$c.\" value=\"$linkid\" /> <p>Opponent No.$c.</p> <select id=\"opponent_id.$c.\"  name=\"opponent_id.$c.\" class=\"form-control input sm select2\">.$OpponentOptions.
            <option value=\"$opponent_id\" selected>$opponent</option>
            </select>
                        $( \"#AppendForm\" ).append(str);";
       
                    }
            }
             $echomsg.= " });
                    </script>";
                    echo $echomsg;
                      //var_dump($echomsg);
            }
              }
         ?>
```

Following is the form html

```
          <form role="form" method="post">
          select case
           <select id="case_id" name="case_id" class="form-control input sm select2" required>
             <?php echo $options; ?>
           </select>
           <input type="submit" value="Check existing opponents" id="checkexistingopp" name="checkexistingopp" />
           </form> 

          <form  id="AppendForm" role="form" method="post" >

            </form>
```

Screenshot of the Console
[image: screenshot of console]

But on click of the button nothing is happening
Can someone suggest any solution?
Thanks for the answers in advance

Comment: Any Console errors?

Comment: Not the issue you're asking but, you are open to SQL injections and using very old SQL joins. Use a `join` and an `on` condition for how it relates.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of doing this with jQuery. Why aren't you populating your form with the desired content directly in PHP? Why do you feel you need to wait for the page to load in order to do that?

Comment: ADyson.. The console shows the following errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Also, what do you expect to happen and on the click of which button?

Comment: El_Vanja Because the data to load depends on the user selection of the case id. it will populate data only if there exist records belonging to that case id else it shouldnt have anything. This is to allow users to edit the opponents of a case when selected. I expect that the dropdown is created under form with id `"AppendForm"` on click on button with id `"checkexistingopp"`

Comment: Is this whole thing happening in an AJAX call? If not, then it seems you have fundamentally misunderstood how requests to the server work.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`...there should be more than that. And it should give you a line number.

Comment: ADyson. Please check the screenshot of the console in the edited question

Comment: El_Vanja. I am not using AJAX here. Just using simple jquery

Comment: Hi don't use jquery that way instead you can `echo $echomsg;` directly inside your `<form  id="AppendForm" role="form" method="post" > //here echo that </form>` remove all jquery code and only keep php code .

Comment: @Fard ok and which line is line 532? If you click it, it will take you there.

Comment: But...as the others are saying, there seems to be no reason for doing this with javascript/jQuery. You're executing the JS when the page loads, it's not doing anything useful like waiting for user input before acting...so it would be far simpler to just let PHP render these form elements directly.

Comment: ADyson.. How can I append a dropdown to that specific form using php without javascript/jquery when the selected case id has records?

Comment: and also it will execute this only when the button is clicked so it will do that after DOM is fully loaded and the button is clicked. So currently its not that its not waiting for user input since it will execute only if the button is clicked after DOM is loaded. ADyson

Comment: At the moment you're using PHP to create some Javascript code e.g. `$echomsg.=" str=\"<br> ...` etc. But within the javascript code, it generates some HTML. The entire contents of that HTML is based on data that PHP provides. So, instead of using PHP to make Javascript which then makes HTML, why not just use PHP to make HTML directly? Then you can echo it into the correct place in your page, without needing Javascript. Nothing that you've shown above requires any javascript.

Comment: `also it will execute this only when the button is clicked`...no, it will execute when the page is loaded. That's what `$(document).ready(function()` ensures. By "button click", I assume maybe you mean "when a form is submitted". If so, that causes a POST request to your server. That means that _a new page_ is loaded from your server to your browser in response. This javascript you're generating will run when that _new page_ is created. It has nothing to do with the page which was there previously. As El_vanja said eariler, I think maybe you don't understand web application lifecyles very well

Comment: Think of it like this (simplified): Always render first form. Only render the second form if the first one is submitted. So at first the page loads, user sees first form. Fills out, submits. New request happens, this time the form is submitted and the page is reloaded showing both forms. All that is required to achieve this is one `if` condition around the second form, that checks if `$_POST` contains variables from the first form.

Comment: I understood your point.. I was actually initially working on the GUI that allowed to add drop down based on click so unconsciously was applying the same thing here. This is so basic I could just echo where needed I feel stupid.. Thanks alot ADyson

Comment: Don't worry too much. Even experienced developers sometimes make beginner level mistakes and feel stupid afterwards. I consider it a normal part of the developer lifecycle. If you code, you will do or say something stupid periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just make PHP render the form elements directly? None of this appears to require any JavaScript. The Javascript/jQuery is not adding any value in this situation.

e.g.

```
  $echomsg = "";

  if ($results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql))
  {
    $c = 0;

    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
      $linkid = $result->LinkId;
      $RefNumber = $result->refnumber;
      $case_id = $result->case_id;
      $opponent_id = $result->opponent_id;
      $opponent = $result->Opponent;
      $c++;  //counter to differentiate names and ids of html elements
    
      if (isset(opponent_id)) {
        $echomsg .= '<br><br>
          <input type="hidden" id="LinkId'.$c.'" name="LinkId'.$c.'" value="'.$linkid.'" />
          <p>Opponent No'.$c.'</p>
          <select id="opponent_id'.$c.'" name="opponent_id'.$c.'" class="form-control input sm select2">'.$OpponentOptions.'
          <option value="$opponent_id" selected>'.$opponent.'</option>
          </select>';
      }
   }

   //....
  ?>
  <form  id="AppendForm" role="form" method="post">
    <?php echo $echomsg; ?>
  </form>
```

N.B. I don't know where `$OpponentOptions` is supposed to come from? I guess this is set earlier in your script somewhere. In the absence of other info I will assume it's correct and meaningful.